# Which should I choose between AUC, f-score, accuracy or recall?

Tags: data-structures, data-mining

I have a problem to choose the best result for the selection models

| Model | AUC | Accuracy | f-score | Precision | Recall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kNN | 0.968 | 0.997 | 0.997 | 0.997 | 0.997 |
| SVM | 0.965 | 0.994 | 0.994 | 0.994 | 0.994 |
| ANN | 0.972 | 0.982 | 0.973 | 0.965 | 0.982 |
| Logistic | 0.965 | 0.997 | 0.997 | 0.997 | 0.997 |

Between these models, what should I choose and using what parameters (AUC, ACC, f-score, Presicion, Recall) should I use?

Comment: Welcome at stack**overflow**. Choose `the best result for the selection models` or *model and parameters for best results*?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a lot depends on the dataset. But based on your scores, "kNN" should be the better choice.
But again everything depends on the dataset and how you split it into train-test-validation. Normally "kNN" is not the best choice for classification problems when you can use "SVM", "XGboost, or "Catboost".
Normally in classification problems, a higher f1-score is always better. If you get that the f-1 score is high, it is unnecessary to care about the "AUC" score and "accuracy" because the f-1 score is the combination of accuracy and AUC score.

Thank you! It is all from my perspective and my knowledge!

Comment: I see... because i already split into training and testing... the result between train8bg and testing both are almost the same.. just i dont know how to choose.. I read a lot  journals and articles, most of the researcher take AUC result. but when i googled it most says that i should consider f1-score. So now i should choose f1-score right? what about AUC and accuracy? when it is needed?

Comment: Yes you should choose f1-score. But if your dataset is small, then choosing f-1 score might not give you the best result. Because in small dataset, the accuracy is never the best choice. As f-1 score is the combination between accuracy and AUC score then for small dataset f-1 score might not be the best option. In that case you should use AUC score.
If your dataset is large enough like about at least seven to eight thousand rows then you should use f-1 score.
Thank you!

Comment: my datasets are 9665 altogether.. but for above result is from testing datasets which i split it into 70% which is  6765... so i guess from your opinion my datasets for testing datasets are not enough isnt it? should i consider to take AUC result then?

Comment: Yes! I think AUC will be the better option for your dataset!

Comment: Alright, thank you so much sir for lending your time sharing your thoughts