# Accuracy, AUC, or F1 for Binary Classification without threshold

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, auc, precision-recall

I am currently building a binary classification model to predict stock price movements (trend prediction). More specifically, the model predicts the probability that a stock outperforms the daily median return:

```
>Class 0: return >= median
>
>Class 1: return < median return
```

Accordingly, I (should) be dealing with a balanced prediction problem.

The ten stocks with the highest probability will be bought, and the ten stocks with the lowest probability will be shorted daily. So, ideally, the model performs well on *both classes* (I use softmax, so the model must exclusively decide).

I am wondering whether I should use the Accuracy, F1 or AUC-ROC when choosing the optimal model under these circumstances?

My understanding is that both are suitable metrics when the two classes are equally important. This [StackExchange-Answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/806/advantages-of-auc-vs-standard-accuracy) recommends the AUC over Accuracy because it will "strongly discourage people going for models that are representative, but not discriminative (...) and [only] select models that achieve false positive and true positive rates that are significantly above random chance, which is not guaranteed for accuracy". In contrast, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827173/which-should-i-choose-between-auc-f-score-accuracy-or-recall) recommends the F1-Score because it is the combination of accuracy and AUC score.

I guess what's confusing me is that I will make use of both classes based on the probabilty assigned by the model. Also, I do not have an imbalanced dataset which usually calls for using the AUC-ROC.

Which evaluation metric should I choose to find the optimal model on validation data?

Thanks a lot for any thoughts or recommendations.

Comment: Why not logloss? It would penalize more for the bigger certainty of a wrong class, which sounds like exactly what you'd want.

Comment: I am currently using binary_crossentropy as the loss function and the labels on the training data are binary [1, 0] for class 0 and [0, 1] for class 1. Based on the context,  do you suggest switching binary crossentropy to logloss in model.compile()? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's the same thing in this context. That means you're already optimizing for logloss, and your loss function also looks like the most suitable evaluation metric to me.